# Html/css width of screen

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

On my page, there is a little of the page the goes past the screen on the right, making a    x-scrollbar at the bottom of the page, how can i get rid of the scroll bar at the bottom?

Comment: Jsfiddle or Page Link pLease

Answer (score 0):

Watch out for a wave of downvotes, you might want to provide more information.
Anyhow, try

```
body { 
    overflow: none;
}
```

You probably got sizing issues however. Might want to post your code.